# Using the Product Rule

Tags: calculus

I have to calculate the derivative for $f(x) = (\sqrt{x} + 102)(\sqrt{x} - 101)$.
I think I have to use the product rule for this, but am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can use the product rule.

$$\frac{df}{dx}=u'v+v'u$$

In this case let $u=\sqrt x-101$ and $v=\sqrt x +102$

Then $$\frac{df(u,v)}{dx}=1+x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

after simplifying.

Alternatively you can expand the brackets and don't worry about the product $-101 \cdot 102$ because it will disappear when you differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  First, expand
$$f(x) = (\sqrt{x} + 102)(\sqrt{x} - 101).$$

Then, there will be no need to use the Product Rule for differentiation.

Can you take it from here?